# Error (209015): Can't configure device. Expected JTAG ID code 0x02D010DD for device 2, but found JTAG ID code 0x00000000

Tags: jtag, error, cyclone

I'm having a weird problem where i cant upload my design to the  DE0-NANO board, gives me the weird error message which is the title of this question.

Any other design uploads fine and I have done nothing different. Restarted the computer, rewrote the project, checked if the correct device is chosen and updated all the drivers, still doesn't upload.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your JTAG can't see the device. You have some configuration problem we won't be able to help you with without more information.

Comment: Looks like you probably have a bad connection somewhere, seeing as it's finding a 0x00000000 ID.

Comment: Of something wrong with the tool configuration that is tied to the particular project which is failing - assuming that you actually mean that you can still load other files to the same device.

Comment: It loads everything else except for the one project, stops at 73%. Once it gives me the error the pc doesn't recognize the device but turning the board off and on solves the problem.

The design im loading is a PWM generator which is lead by a clock divider, nothing too complicated. What other info would you like?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I named the .sdc file differently from the name of the project. Creating a new one with the right one solved the issue, not sure why, but here we are.